# In SQL Server, how to create while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have the following :
I used the select to got the Id from table as follow :

```
Select Id from t
```

data will be like this:

```
id  
DG1 
FS2
DD4
```

I want to pass result the result to the following sql statement using while or case
Depend of the result of the select statement

```
SELECT f.age_days, f.Body_wt,f.Act_Fcr_Day,f.Act_Growth ,
f.growth_gm as Growth ,f2.growth_gm as Growth1,
   COALESCE(
   (
   SELECT TOP 1 Body_wt
   FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] mi
   WHERE mi.Age_Days > f.Age_Days and     mi.flock_id = ??????
   ORDER BY
         Age_Days   
   ), 0) - f.Body_wt AS diff
FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] f
```

How can I do it .

thanks

Comment: Please, re-arrange your question into a readable form and put some additional effort to make it English-wise comprehensible.

Comment: Why not just use all of them at once and run one query and return one dataset?  then you can use `mi.flock_id IN (select Id from t)`

Comment: Are you certain that you need a loop at all? In general, if you're working directly with data in SQL Server and using a loop, you're *probably* doing it wrong. Work in sets.

Answer (score 0):

I find this type of logic easier to follow with `outer apply`:

```
SELECT f.age_days, f.Body_wt, f.Act_Fcr_Day, f.Act_Growth,
       f.growth_gm as Growth, f2.growth_gm as Growth1,
       (COALESCE(mi.Body_wt, 0) - f.Body_wt0 AS diff
FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] f OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 mi.*
      FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] mi
      WHERE mi.Age_Days > f.Age_Days and mi.flock_id = ??????
      ORDER BY mi.Age_Days   
     ) mi;
```

Then, if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT t.id, f.age_days, f.Body_wt, f.Act_Fcr_Day, f.Act_Growth,
       f.growth_gm as Growth, f2.growth_gm as Growth1,
       (COALESCE(mi.Body_wt, 0) - f.Body_wt0 AS diff
FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] f CROSS JOIN
     (Select Id from t
     ) t OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 mi.*
      FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] mi
      WHERE mi.Age_Days > f.Age_Days and mi.flock_id = t.id
      ORDER BY mi.Age_Days   
     ) mi;
```

This also includes the `id` in the `SELECT`, because that seems desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions in `VARCHAR` columns are not advised. If you have a Primary Key or a surrogate key which can be used, then it will be helpful. Use the below query to use `WHILE LOOP`.

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(10) = ''
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SELECT @Id = MIN(Id) from t WHERE Id > @Id
    IF @Id IS NULL
        BREAK
    SELECT f.age_days, f.Body_wt,f.Act_Fcr_Day,f.Act_Growth ,
    f.growth_gm as Growth ,f2.growth_gm as Growth1,
       COALESCE(
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 Body_wt
       FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] mi
       WHERE mi.Age_Days > f.Age_Days and     mi.flock_id = @Id
       ORDER BY
             Age_Days   
       ), 0) - f.Body_wt AS diff
    FROM [dbo].[Broiler_Farms_Data] f
END
```